# Perl program to get the word types as output

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I am trying to get the word type as an output from an input file (input.txt) which looks like this,

Input file

```
John    N   N
loved   V
Mary    N   N
.   S

He  N
was V
eating  V
in  P   P
a   A   A
restaurant  N
.   S

The A   A
cats    N   N
killed  V
the A   A
rats    N   N
 .  S

I   N
am  V
playing V
.   S
```

The input file has three columns. The first column are the words and the next two columns are the word types. All the columns are separated by tab and there are blank lines in between. 
 The objective of the program is to match the word endings like "ing","ed" and "s" and print the word types in the fourth column. The expected output will be

Expected output

```
John    N   N
loved   V       V
Mary    N   N
.   S

He  N
was V
eating  V       V
in  P   P
a   A   A
restaurant  N
.   S

The A   A
cats    N   N   N
killed  V       V
the A   A
rats    N   N   N
.   S

I   N
am  V
playing V       V
.   S
```

The code that I am using is this,

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<' , 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp ;
    print $_;
    if (/ing\s*$/ or /ed\s*$/) {
        print '  V';
    } 
    if (/s\s*$/) {
        print '  N';
    }
    print "\n";
    }
close($fh);
```

However I believe I am doing something wrong as I am getting the input file itself as the output. Please help me with some directions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 'ing' or 'ed' aren't at the end of the line, but rather at the end of the first word, so something like `/^\w*ing\s/` and `/^\w*ed\s/` would do the job maybe?

Comment: @Dada Thanks for your reply. But that did not help. I guess I have to store  the first column of words in hash and try to compare them with  particularly the word endings. Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: @Dada Your suggestion works just fine. You correctly spotted the `/...$/` problem in the OP's script.

Comment: @PerlDog Yea I thought so. Thanks for mentionning my comment in your answer btw :)

Answer (score 3):

You were almost right and [Dada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990392/dada) pointed you in the right direction with his comment.

The pattern `/ing\s*$/` checks for the string `'ing'` followed by optional whitespace (`\s*`) and then end-of-line (`$`). This won't match your input because after e.g. `'eating'` there is a tab ***and*** the letter `V` before the line ends.

You have to change that pattern to `/^\w*ing\b/`. It means

- start of the line `^`
- some optional word characters (like a-z, 0-9) `\w*`
- the string `'ing'`
- a word boundary, i.e. a change from letters to non-letters `\b`

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    print $_;
    if ( /^\w*ing\b/ or /^\w*ed\b/ ) {
        print "\tV";
    }
    if (/^\w*s\b/) {
        print "\tN";
    }
    print "\n";
}
close($fh);
```

This gives *almost* the desired output but fails at `'was'`: It ends in `s` and thus is considered a noun, but that's a different problem:

```
John    N   N
loved   V   V
Mary    N   N
.   S

He  N
was V   N
eating  V   V
in  P   P
a   A   A
restaurant  N
.   S

The A   A
cats    N   N   N
killed  V   V
the A   A
rats    N   N   N
 .  S

I   N
am  V
playing V   V
.   S
```

---

Btw: [Dada's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996331/perl-program-to-get-the-word-types-as-output#comment63436820_37996331) gives the same result. He proposed the pattern `/^\w*ing\s/` instead of my `/^\w*ing\b/` which also works because after an `'ing'` you have always a whitespace `\s` in your input.